# Keeping score on refresh javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a roll the dice game. When player 1s dice is bigger then he wins and vice versa.

I have added a variable to track the score, however on refreshing the page a new game starts and I have to start over.

How do I keep the score from resetting?

```js
var score1 = 0;

if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!";
  score1++;
  document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = score1;
}
```

Comment: Are  you running on a web server (and have access to it) or just a standalone HTML page?
If you're running on a web server you can take advantages or sessions, if you're not, then you can use the localStorage methods available in JS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can try pushing the score to a cookie (or to localStorage as @Rylee mentioned) instead if you want the data to persist on reload. ALso, please post relevant code snippets of your HTML as well.

Comment: You can use sessionStorage on or off a server. If you need the score to persist for the user, use localStorage, if you need to save the score on the server, use AJAX and a database

Comment: I made you a snippet. The code you present does not look like the part where you need to persist the score

Answer (score 0):

try [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want to keep it only in the same browser.

**set**

```
localStorage.setItem('score', score1);
```

**get**

```
score1 = localStorage.getItem('score'); //parse
```

if you need more (across browsers, managed by logins, etc.), you can keep it in a database

Comment: You say `parse` but don't

Answer (score 0):

One way to remember a value would be using something like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

**Note:** `localStorage` doesn't work on StackOverflow so the below code won't work here. Also, you need to put the javascript at the bottom of the `body` like below so the `h1` and `div` elements already exist when you try to target them with the script.

Copy this code and paste in your environment to test it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><h1>
    <div id="score1"></div>
    <div id="score2"></div>

    <script>
    var score1 = 0;
    var score2 = 0;
    var message = "";

    function getRandom(min, max) {
        // random number between min and max, both inclusive
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('score1') !== null && 
        localStorage.getItem('score2') !== null &&
        localStorage.getItem('message') !== null) {
        score1 = localStorage.getItem('score1');
        score2 = localStorage.getItem('score2');
        message = localStorage.getItem('message');
    } else {
        score1 = getRandom(1, 10);
        score2 = getRandom(1, 10);
    
        if(score1 > score2) {
            message = "Player 1 wins!";
            score1++;
        } else if(score1 < score2) {
            message = "Player 2 wins!";
            score2++;
        } else {
            message = "It was a tie!";
            score1++;
            score2++;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('score1', score1);
        localStorage.setItem('score2', score2);
        localStorage.setItem('message', message);
    }

    document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = "Player 1: " + score1;
    document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = "Player 2: " + score2;
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = message;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```